# Docker stalls on run - Wait Condition Exit

Tags: docker

Trying to run a small 100mb docker image. It does run in the end, but takes about 5 minutes to successfully run. When it does run it gives me the below error:

```
time="2018-09-25T10:20:28+01:00" level=error msg="error waiting for container: error during connect: Post http://XYZ/v1.32/containers/933e895a7a1429199f053ab6f384589307c927ebe9833f368352e196246308a0/wait?condition=next-exit: EOF"
```

I've googled it and it doesn't seem to come up in search results. Is there any way I can find out what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the provided URL:

```
http://XYZ/v1.32/containers/{...container_ID...}/wait?condition=next-exit
```

one may assume that what gives you this error tries to talk to the Docker Engine API and more specifically to [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.32/#operation/ContainerWait) endpoint:

> ```
>  POST /containers/{id}/wait
> ```
>
> #### Wait for a container
>
> Block until a container stops, then returns the exit code.
>
> *query Parameters:*
>
> ```
>  condition string     "not-running"
> ```
>
> Wait until a container state reaches the given condition, either `'not-running'` (default), `'next-exit'`, or `'removed'`.

...but has a connection problem.